# Why variable inside & outside function returns different result?

Tags: javascript

why **console.log(getComputerChoice());** prints random value of arrayNum, but
**console.log(randomValue);**  prints  one same value, everytime they are called.

```js
arrayNum = [1, 2, 4];

const getComputerChoice = () => {

  let randomValue = arrayNum[Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayNum.length)];
  return randomValue;
}

let randomValue = arrayNum[Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayNum.length)];

console.log(getComputerChoice());
console.log(getComputerChoice());
console.log(getComputerChoice());
console.log(getComputerChoice());
console.log(getComputerChoice());
console.log(getComputerChoice());

console.log(randomValue);
console.log(randomValue);
console.log(randomValue);
console.log(randomValue);
console.log(randomValue);
console.log(randomValue);
```

Comment: Because you don't reassign it after each log.

Comment: `getComputerChoice` generates a new random number each time it's called (which you then log). `randomValue` is only created once but you log that value repeatedly.

Comment: Your code is like this: (1) choose a random value, (2) print a random value (6 times), (3) print the random value that was chosen in step 1 (6 times)